# python sshtunnel ssh to proxy

Tags: python, linux, proxy, socks

I want create proxy/socks service from my ssh linux server. I already created port forwarder with sshtunnel for mysql, example code:

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL

with SSHTunnelForwarder(('mydomain.com', 22), ssh_username='root', ssh_password='password', local_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3306), remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 3306)) as server:
    myDB = URL(drivername='mysql+pymysql', host='127.0.0.1', database='test_db', username='root', password='THawr_tapH3f', port=3306)

    engine = create_engine(name_or_url=myDB)
    connection = engine.connect()    
    connection.close()
```

I want to transform my ssh linux machine in proxy/socks4/5 service with python; how can I do this?

Comment: Does it need to be python? `ssh -D 1080 mydomain.com` makes ssh listening port 1080 and working as socks5 proxy.

Comment: is simple your solution, but need in python for use in my application